# DragMove() and Maximize

Tags: wpf, drag, move, maximize

I have a problem with my custom window (AllowTransparency, WindowStyle=None) in WPF. DragMove() method works good, but when I maximize window, or it maximizing automatically by Windows 7 Aero Snap, this method does not work at all. So I can't unsnap window with mouse drag and return it state to WindowState.Normal. Left and Right Aero Snap works good, I can snap and unsnap window without a problem. But when it maximized, nothing works except Win+Down  combination. Maybe somebody knows how to solve this problem or where can I find other ways to do proper DragMove of custom window with working Aero Snap features?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my method. Try make it shorter )))

```
private void InitHeader()
{
    var border = Find<Border>("borderHeader");
    var restoreIfMove = false;

    border.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            if ((ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize) ||
                (ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip))
            {
                SwitchState();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                restoreIfMove = true;
            }

            DragMove();
        }
    };
    border.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) =>
    {
        restoreIfMove = false;
    };
    border.MouseMove += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (restoreIfMove)
        {
            restoreIfMove = false;
            var mouseX = e.GetPosition(this).X;
            var width = RestoreBounds.Width;
            var x = mouseX - width / 2;

            if (x < 0)
            {
                x = 0;
            }
            else
            if (x + width > screenSize.X)
            {
                x = screenSize.X - width;
            }

            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            Left = x;
            Top = 0;
            DragMove();
        }
    };
}

private void SwitchState()
{
    switch (WindowState)
    {
        case WindowState.Normal:
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            break;
        }
        case WindowState.Maximized:
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

(To get screenSize I use native methods)

Comment: @groaner can you point to the screenSize native method you used?

Comment: I need an evaluation of if Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed every time I do DragMove(); to avoid "Can only call DragMove when primary mouse button is down". Also, WindowState should be set to WindowState.Normal before evaluating the new x position (var x = mouseX - width / 2; line). With these modifications works perfect, thanks!

Comment: Works best in combination with Anthony M's solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Groaner's solution does not function properly with multiple monitor setups, especially where the primary monitor is not the left-most.

Here is my solution based on his which handles single or multiple monitor setups properly.
In this code 'rctHeader' is a Rectangle defined in the XAML.

```
    private bool mRestoreIfMove = false;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void SwitchWindowState()
    {
        switch (WindowState)
        {
            case WindowState.Normal:
                {
                    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    break;
                }
            case WindowState.Maximized:
                {
                    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }


    private void rctHeader_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            if ((ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize) || (ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip))
            {
                SwitchWindowState();
            }

            return;
        }

        else if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            mRestoreIfMove = true;
            return;
        }

        DragMove();
    }


    private void rctHeader_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        mRestoreIfMove = false;
    }


    private void rctHeader_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mRestoreIfMove)
        {
            mRestoreIfMove = false;

            double percentHorizontal = e.GetPosition(this).X / ActualWidth;
            double targetHorizontal = RestoreBounds.Width * percentHorizontal;

            double percentVertical = e.GetPosition(this).Y / ActualHeight;
            double targetVertical = RestoreBounds.Height * percentVertical;

            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

            POINT lMousePosition;
            GetCursorPos(out lMousePosition);

            Left = lMousePosition.X - targetHorizontal;
            Top = lMousePosition.Y - targetVertical;

            DragMove();
        }
    }



    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

In WPF I would highly recommend using [Control.PointToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) when restoring the window before your [Window.DragMove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dragmove(v=vs.110).aspx). PointToScreen will also handle multiple monitor setups. This would simplify the restore to the following:

```
    private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
        if( e.ClickCount == 2 )
        {
            if( ResizeMode != ResizeMode.CanResize && 
                ResizeMode != ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip )
            {
                return;
            }

            WindowState = WindowState == WindowState.Maximized
                ? WindowState.Normal
                : WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            mRestoreForDragMove = WindowState == WindowState.Maximized;
            DragMove();
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseMove( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
    {
        if( mRestoreForDragMove )
        {
            mRestoreForDragMove = false;

            var point = PointToScreen( e.MouseDevice.GetPosition( this ) );

            Left = point.X - ( RestoreBounds.Width * 0.5 );
            Top = point.Y;

            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

            DragMove();
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
        mRestoreForDragMove = false;
    }

    private bool mRestoreForDragMove;
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Compared to the other solutions this is working the best - it has its minor flaws but it works really good nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

A little late for another answer, but my code was simpler so I'll put it here.
The left and right snapping works just fine but when the window is Maximized or snaps to upper screen bounds and maximizes, the DragMove method will not work! So here is what I did:

---

Just handle the Mouse_Down Event on the element you want to drag with like this:

```
private void TitleBar_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        var point = PointToScreen(e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(this));

        if (point.X <= RestoreBounds.Width / 2)
            Left = 0;

        else if (point.X >= RestoreBounds.Width)
            Left = point.X - (RestoreBounds.Width - (this.ActualWidth - point.X));

        else
            Left = point.X - (RestoreBounds.Width / 2);

        Top = point.Y - (((FrameworkElement)sender).ActualHeight / 2);
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
    DragMove(); 
}
```

I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Ocasionally it happens that the window gets back to a normal state but does not anchor to the mouse which is really irritating.

Answer (score 2):

The DragMove() method only works in the titlebar of the form so use:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

public static void StartDrag(Window window)
{
    WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
    SendMessage(helper.Handle, 161, 2, 0);
}
```

**Dont forget to add System.Windows.Interop**

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog post on this:

http://dragablz.net/2014/12/16/getting-windows-snap-to-play-with-wpf-borderless-windows/

Comment: I'm sorry but the blog post is almost useless, it actually requires to rip apart the entire project you mention in the blog post and get out what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing the finest implementation to date, ensuring a smooth user experience:

```
private void GrabOrMaximizeWindow(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ClickCount >= 2)
            MaximizeWindow(sender, e);
        else {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) { 
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;                  
                Point p = e.GetPosition(null);                    
                Top = p.Y - 50;
                Left = p.X - Width/2;
            }
            DragMove();
        }
    }
```

With added comments for clarity:

```
private void GrabOrMaximizeWindow(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Maximize the window on double-click.
    if (e.ClickCount >= 2)
        MaximizeWindow(sender, e);
    // Drag The window.
    else 
    {
       /* Problem: Can't drag the window when maximized.
        * Solution: Un-maximize!
        * 
        * Problem: Un-maximizing teleports the window to 
                   its original location, hindering dragging.
        * Solution: Move the window to the cursor (intersect 
                    with cursor at the middle-top of the window).
        */
        if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) 
        { 
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;                  
            Point p = e.GetPosition(null);
            // Adjust the top position with a 50px margin to 
            // allow for maximized vs. docked window.
            Top = p.Y - 50;
            Left = p.X - Width/2;
        }

        DragMove();
    }
}
```

For a fully working example, create a *MainWindow.xaml* using the following:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="KanbanPrototype.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KanbanPrototype"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="" Height="900" Width="1600"
    WindowStyle="None" 
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="CanResize">

    <!-- Generates a resizable window border in all directions. -->
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome 
            CaptionHeight="0"
            ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="130"/> <!-- Define Header -->
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>  <!-- Define Body -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Header -->
        <Grid MouseLeftButtonDown="GrabOrMaximizeWindow">  <!-- Here is our Method! -->
            <!-- Header Color and Title -->
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="SkyBlue"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="看板!"  FontSize="64" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```